# Stop page post back on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to open a `dialog box` on click of a `button` which is inside `gridview`

but what happens is, whenever I click on button the page is getting refreshed. I tried giving `UseSubmitBehavior=false` but still my page is getting postback.

Here is my `button`

```
<asp:Button ID="FlAttachParty" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="25px" Text="Add Attachment" OnClick="FlAttachParty_Click" CausesValidation="false"  />
```

Kindly suggest how to achieve this

**update**

server side code

```
protected void FlAttachParty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (strMode == "A")
    {
        if (HidAttachParty.Value == "")
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
            OracleCommand objpricmd = new OracleCommand("select xxcus.xxacl_pn_party_info_SEQ.nextval from dual", ObjPriCon);
            HidAttachParty.Value = Convert.ToString(objpricmd.ExecuteOracleScalar());
            ObjPriCon.Close();
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "AttachmentCallParty(" + HidAttachParty.Value + ");", true);
    }
    else
    {
        if (HidAttachParty.Value == "")
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
            OracleCommand ObjPriCmd = new OracleCommand("select xxcus.xxacl_pn_party_info_SEQ.nextval from dual", ObjPriCon);
            HidAttachParty.Value = Convert.ToString(ObjPriCmd.ExecuteOracleScalar());
            ObjPriCon.Close();
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "AttachmentCallParty(" + HidAttachParty.Value + ");", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your server side code. You may need updatepanel.

Comment: @Vicky_Thinking: updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Asp:Button` is a server control and for send request to server and get response need page refresh.

The  control renders markup as , regardless of whether or not you have a OnClick event tied to it. This means that your form will be submitted to the server upon click, unless you stop it with javascript.

One solution is using `Ajax` Call.

Another solution is to use an `HTML` button and bind a `click` event handler.

```
<input type="button" id="BtnGo" class="button" value="Go" runat="server" onclick="funShortcuts()" style="height: 21px; width: 40px;" />
```

The problem is genereting of `HidAttachID`.

So you can get here in the following way:

```
function funShortcuts() { 
    var str_mkey = ""; 
    var MkeyVal = '<%= Request.QueryString["key"] %>'; 
    if (MkeyVal == "10") { 
       var r1 = confirm('Do you want to open the attachment form ? '); 
    if (MkeyVal > 0) { 
       if (r1 == true) { 
          str_mkey = "'" + MkeyVal + "'"; 
       } 
       else { 
          str_mkey = "'" + MkeyVal + "'"; 
       } 

      var returnPara = window.showModalDialog("../PreSales/Transactions/FrmCrm_File_Attachment.aspx?Entity='XXACL_PN_PARTY_INFO','XXACL_PN_EXPENSE_INFO','XXACL_PN_VIEW_DATA_INFO'&mkey=" + MkeyVal + "&User_Attach=N&userid=<%=Request.QueryString.Get("userid")%>", null, 'unadorned:yes;resizable:1;dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:350px'); 
      document.getElementById('HidCefMkey').value = MkeyVal; 
    } 
    else { 
       alert("Kindly save the form first..!!"); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Adding `onClientclick` doesn't opens my dialog box..why ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but my `OnClick` function is not working,

Comment: still happening the same, not going to `Onclick` function

Comment: now this error `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method` at line `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Please have a look now.

Comment: Are you using `if (!Page.IsPostBack){ //Your code }` ?

Comment: No I m using `!isPostback`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129249/discussion-between-alexandru-ionut-mihai-and-nad).

Comment: Sorry can't chat now. As not available in Office. Do let me know if u need anything

Comment: Yes it is a JavaScript function

Comment: hi, can we come on chat now ?